# Что за предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Рассмотрим комментарий к видео:

> Полупустой зал. Эх, меня там нет.

**Полупустой зал** — это неполное предложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Полупустой зал. Эх, меня там нет.***

1) Предложение **нельзя назвать неполным** (это вполне определенный грамматический термин). Неполными называются предложения, состав которых можно восстановить по контексту.

2) Предложение такого вида может быть **назывным предложением или изолированным номинативом** в зависимости от описываемой ситуации.

*Полупустой зал. Что он напоминает мне?*  Изолированный номинатив, тема для размышления.

*Полупустой зал. Я вхожу и сажусь на последний ряд.* Номинативное предложение, предмет находится в поле зрения наблюдателя.

3) Но в названном примере  **ситуация особенная.** С одной стороны, это вроде бы предмет в поле зрения наблюдателя (номинативное предложение), с другой стороны, чувствуется **оценочное значение наблюдателя  по отношению к залу**, а также  выражается сожаление по поводу его отсутствия в нем: *Зал полупустой. Эх, меня там нет.*

Но предложение "Зал полупустой" является двусоставным. Если в заданном предложении логическое ударение перенести на первое слово, то оно тоже **будет двусоставным (с именным сказуемым):**

***ПолупустОй зал. Эх, меня там нет.***

Comment: Спасибо! Правильно ли, что в этом случае допустимы две интерпретации и в зависимости от интонации меняется тип конструкции?

Comment: Я бы сказала так. Тип конструкции определяется по смыслу и по контексту, а  постановка ударения (интонация) - это уже следствие того, как мы определили грамматику.